# Interface expected here (BaseAdapter)

Tags: android, android-adapter

I'm having a problem in my GalleryFragment where in my BaseAdapter shows "Interface expected here":

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment implements BaseAdapter { //this part

public GalleryFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
   return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

I dont know what to do right now, and I cant move on to the next until I figured this thing out.

Comment: What is `BaseAdapter` here? Are you sure it *is* an interface rather than a class? That's certainly the error message you get when you try to use `implements` with a class...

Comment: (And if it's `android.widget.BaseAdapter`, that is indeed a class...)

Comment: so what do I need to do? I'm trying to create a picture gallery, but instead of putting it in MainActivity, I'm trying to put it in a Fragment so it can cooperate with my Navigation Drawer.

Comment: Well it sounds like you should probably have two classes: one extending Fragment and one extending BaseAdapter.

Comment: Ok, I'll try it out now, see if it works

Comment: you can not extend two classes

Comment: Well yeah you cant, creating another is

Answer (score 2):

you can use like this BaseAdapter is not an interface.

```
public class GalleryFragment extends Fragment  { //this part

    public GalleryFragment () {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        DummyAdapter dummyAdapter=new DummyAdapter();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_gallery, container, false);
    }
    private class DummyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int i) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int i) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`BaseAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) is an abstract class. You have to `extends` it, not `implements` it. Alternately, use an Adapter interface like (for example) [`ListAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html).

Comment: `BaseAdapter` abstract class itself implements `ListAdapter`.

Comment: BaseAdapter is needed. I'll see if creating a two class works